# Will These Temps Cause System Damage

Tags: temperature, speedfan

I have a `AMD FX8350 4.00GHZ` processor and speedfan shows these as my temps.  Temp1 shows a flame beside it, but I know those are "default" settings.  All I am doing is using Handbrake to convert an `.mkv` to an `.mp4`

```
Fan1: 0 RPM
Fan2: 0 RPM
Fan3: 1487 RPM
Fan1: 4561 RPM
Fan2: 0 RPM
Fan3: 1480 RPM
Fan4: 0 RPM
Fan5: 0 RPM
GPU: 44C
Temp1: 60C
Temp2: 39C
Temp3: -128C
HD1: 28C
HD2: 32C
HD0: 29C
HD3: 40C
Core: 49C
```

**Question at hand, are my temps high enough to cause concern?**

**Graphics Card Temps**
[image: Graphics Card]

**Core Temps**
[image: Core Temps]

**Other Temps**
[image: Other Temps]

**EDIT**
Cool Temps are Below:
**Processor Temps**
[image: Processor Temps]

**Video Card Temps**
[image: Video Card]

**Other Temps**
[image: Other Temps]

Comment: The Temp1 at 60C is a bit concerning, but calling it Temp1 doesn't really help.  Are these temps when you are doing the conversion or just idle?  I'd try another temperature tool.  Some motherboards offer a utility to see temperatures, or something like HWMonitor.  See if you can get a better idea of what Temp1 is, if it's CPU temperature, then I'd be worried.  Max operating temperature for that CPU is listed at 61C.  Curious as to what your BIOS has for shutdown temperatures.

Comment: @N.Greene - yes these temps are during conversion.  I will check HWMonitor and edit my post to see if I can get better details for you.

Comment: What does the temperature go to, when just at idle?

Comment: @N.Greene - see edit with images of temps from HWMonitor.  I do not recall right off what the temps are when idle, but DEF not this high.

Comment: Idle temperature would be nice to see, but do you have adequate fans in your case?  Are they all working?  Cleaned recently (blow out dust)?  What's the temperature of the room?

Comment: 2 fans in the case, all are working and functioning.  Computer is < 30 days old, so should not have much dust, but will check that.  Room temp is roughly 70 degrees (thermostat is set on 70 and AC is not running)

Comment: @N.Greene - idle temps have been added.

Comment: For idle to be that low of a temperature then under stress to shoot up to almost max operating (61), I'd think there's something wrong.  You say it's less than 30 days old?  I'd talk to wherever you got the PC from.  If you built it yourself I'd check the CPU fan/heatsink and maybe wipe off the thermal paste and apply new.

Comment: Yes, it is less than 30 days, I have probably had it around 15 days.  It was a custom build, and for whatever reason anytime I use handbrake to convert an mkv to mp4 temps spike like this.  NOTHING else spikes the temps to these levels.

Comment: @N.Greene - would an aftermarket cooler assist with this issue or would that benefit in no way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like that Handbrake is just very intensive on CPU, which searching for "Handbrake causing high temperatures" it seems to be a common problem.  The conversion is a very cpu intense task.  I didn't think about it just being a handbrake issue, until your 2nd to last comment.

Search around, but probably the best thing I would do would be to "set the affinity" in windows to not use all the cores to perform the task.  Albeit, it would take longer to do the conversion, but I would think you wouldn't have as much of temperature rise if you were only using 4 cores instead of 8.

To set the affinity of a process, go to task-manager, and the processes tab.  Find the process for handbrake, handbrake.exe (downloaded HB but didn't have anything to convert), right-click on the process and choose "Set Affinity..."  Then you'll have a list of check-boxes for every core/thread that the process is going to use.  However, it does seem that handbrake.exe launches a handbrakecli.exe for when a conversion happens, but the affinity you set for handbrake.exe should flow down to the handbrakecli.exe.

You'd be able to tell by watch your CPU usage when doing a conversion, and you should notice not as much of a spike in CPU temperatures.

I'd take it down to half used and see how that performs in terms of temperature and speed of conversion.

An aftermarket cooler, might help a few degrees, but I'd venture to say going from 36C no Load to 60C under conversion, it might net you a couple of degrees, but I can't say for sure.

If I was going to do a lot of video converting would I get an aftermarket cooler, probably.

Hope that helps.